# The URL adds /public_html/ after changes in .htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm a newby on using the .htaccess file for making changes on my website.

I want to change a URL automatically by adding the "www." at the begining of the domain name. To do so I enter the following code on the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.arnaldpedros.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.arnaldpedros.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I see allover the web that this is the proper way to do it but when I type arnaldpedros.com in my browser it takes me to:

http://www.arnaldpedros.com/public_html/

Whis is a 404 Not Found page, with the message:

> Not Found 
>   The requested URL /public_html/ was not found on this server.

What I want to do is to type arnaldpedros.com and to automatically go to www.arnaldpedros.com.

It's driving me crazy cause the same happens on many websites I mange. 
Any help please?

Comment: did you set `RewriteBase /`?

Comment: No, I don't know what that means either... What should I do? Thank you Ben!

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Comment: Thank you, I was going over this document when you first wrote about the RewriteBase, now I've added the "RewriteBase /" as you said but the outcome is still the same: 404 Not Found

Here's the code if you @Ben want to take a look:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.arnaldpedros.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.arnaldpedros.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: did you set the correct `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: How can I set the correct 'DocumentRoot'? The code tha'ts on my question is the only code I have in my .htaccess. Thank you!